# Compiler error when using template specialization under Visual C++

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I have the following cpp code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

// C2589 when compiling with specialization, fine when compiling without
template<typename T>
void foo(T value = std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity() )
{
}

// this specialization causes compiler error C2589 above
template<>
void foo<float>( float value )
{
}

int main()
{
    foo<float>();
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile this using Visual Studio 2013, I get the following error:

```
..\check2\main.cpp(5) : error C2589: '::' : illegal token on right side of '::'
..\check2\main.cpp(5) : error C2059: syntax error : '::'
```

The program compiles fine if I don't include the specialization `foo<float>`. The code also compiles fine **including the specialization** under gcc 4.8.4, which indicates some problem with the Visual C++ compiler.

Is the code correct and should it compile? Is there a workaround for Visual C++?

Comment: I have the same error on VS2015, but it compiles [here](http://ideone.com/ttD7BH).

Comment: @Ben: Good point. I didn't know about this site. I couldn't figure out which compiler they use but since it compiles successfully I assume its gcc. It puzzles me why it compiles with gcc but fails with VC++.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of specializations, I do overloads without the "template" keyword, like this:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T value)
{
}

void foo(float value)
{
}
```

I use these in gcc and Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: That is not specialization.  This is overloading.

Comment: Well, if the compiler won't do specializations properly, then overloading seems to be a good way to work around the problem, which was part of the original question.

Comment: I agree but *When I do specializations, I do them without the "template" keyword, like this:* means that when you do a specialization you use the flowing code.  I am informing you that this is not specialization at all but overloading.  You could word it like *Instead of specializing the template you can just add an overload that takes a `float`*

Answer (score 3):

By omitting the parameter when calling `foo<float>();` you are placing compiler into a conundrum. Compiler simultaneously concludes that specialized function is the right one to choose because you explicitly say `<float>`, and is not the one because there is no parameter. Compiler then reaches for the general version, but it can't because there is a specialized one. Even HAL9000 couldn't figure out that one, unless it's built with gcc. VC++ incorrectly handles the situation. Probably a bug, and not "by design".

Workaround for Visual C++ is to use overloading:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T value)
{
}

template<typename T>
void foo()
{
    foo(std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity());
}
```

And call it as usual `foo<float>();`

Comment: The error message observed by the OP is weird though. Any idea why it's coming up with _that_ particular error message?

Comment: I have to think this is a bug in the parse of the functions by MSVS.  Clang, g++ and ICC all compile the OP's problem without an issue.

Comment: @mindriot I can only guess that the compiler reaches for base template, but not with the "clear mind", and so cannot actually use the base template. Doesn't really matter why that particular message. It's a bug.

Comment: I am not fully convinced with this answer:
1. The fact that it is forbidden to specify default arguments for template specializations implies, that default arguments in the function template also apply to its specializations (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4050418/5969590))
2. If there is an ambiguity causing the problem, I would expect the compiler to state so.
3. The code discussed should (fail to) compile consistently across compilers. To me this hints at a deeper problem with VC++.