# Why am I allowed to explicitly instantiate a template specialization where the default argument is not implicitly convertible to the other type?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

See the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T = int>
void func(T t = 1)
{
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

template void func<int>(int); // Explicit instantion of `int`
template void func<std::string>(std::string); // Explicit instantiation of `std::string` -- why does this not give the same error as below?

int main()
{
    func(); // Outputs "1" - OK
    func(std::string("test")); // Outputs "test" - OK
    // func<std::string>(); // Explicit instantiation - Fails (as expected!): could not convert '1' from 'int' to 'std::string'
}
```

I would have thought that the `template void func<std::string>(std::string);` line would be illegal, as the default `int` argument can't be converted implicitly to `std::string` (similar to how I get a compilation error on the last invocation), and that I would have to resort to the solution outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4050418/3013887).

**When I have a function template with a default argument, why am I allowed to explicitly instantiate a template specialization where the default argument is not implicitly convertible to the other type?** This turns out to be exactly what I wanted, but I'm curious to know how the compiler figures things out.

Comment: Which compiler and version?

Comment: Both `T= int ` and `t=1` are just default parameter when the parameter is empty. It doesn't mean the parameter must be convertible to that.

Comment: @texasbruce I guess I thought the compiler would try to instantiate something like `void func<std::string>(std::string t = 1);` by just replacing the parameter `T`, but your comment makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You can think the way that default parameter is not part of function instantiation, but function call. When you call the function and miss a parameter, the compiler will add that to the function call, but not in the template instantiation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default template parameter and its default value are specified for the function template `func` which means that they are considered only when the template is not instantiated with any type and value.

So `func(std::string("test"));` call uses the explicit instantiation of the template with `std::string` and succeed.

Whereas `func<std::string>();` will fail because explicit instantiation of the template with `std::string` is used but the default value of the parameter is `1` (which is an `int`).

This is equivalent to:

```
func<std::string>(1);
```

And the compiler (GCC 8.2) reports the same error for both these calls.

```
<source>:18:23: note:   cannot convert '1' (type 'int') to type 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'
```

See demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/vwJs0l).

Comment: I think my reasoning fell short on the `...which means that they are considered only when the template is not instantiated with any type and value.` which of course makes a lot of sense.